# TeamSpeak3 Server Migration

Tags: mysql, linux, migration

I'm looking for a solution to copy all ts3 settings from one linux machine to another. That includes all user settings, channels, server settings etc. Actually a complete migration. The Problem is, that I used mysqlite as db for ts3 and now mysql. So how do I have to do this now?

Any suggestion helps!

Thank you in advance.

Marco

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will be closed on the StackOverflow, but it would be likely ontopic on the https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i've done it a while ago:

1. Download the SQLite database
2. Download SQliteExplorer
   (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)
3. Export the database to SQL file using the SQliteExplorer
4. Import the SQL into the MySQL database
5. Create a .ini file that is fired when running your teamspeak server
   that contains the connection parameters

Comment: Do you know where I can find the sqlite db on the server?

Comment: In de root of the teamspeak folder.